# select dynamics with button - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an input that when placing a value generates dynamic select and every time I select a dynamic select load another one, now what I need is that where the button of the plus "+" appears it generates the dynamic statements and that they are not generated alone when I select a select.

**What I need is for the "+" button to work and it will generate the dynamic selects, and that as well as this, so that another dynamic select is generated, I have to select a number in the same select and automatically another select is generated.**

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-roman-xyj0q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: please rewrite this post , it is unclear on what you need help with

Comment: ready already specify more